# Bar plot showing count of values

Tags: powerbi, bar-chart, hana, counting

I am working with a DB through Direct Query and, since I can't make use of Power Query, I'm having a hard time getting around a simple bar plot that displays the values of a column depending on how many of them appear. If this is my column:

**NAME**
Jeff,
Jeff,
Jeff,
Rose,
Rose,
Rose,
James

Then I've got 2 names appearing 3 times and only one that appears once; therefore, my barplot should show a bigger bar that reaches number 2 on Y-axis with a 3 below the X-axis, and a smaller one with a 1.

So far, I've tried this measure

`CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'),FILTER('Table','Table'[NAME]))`

to no avail, since it seems my ODB won't let me work with my table without grouping by columns (?).

I hope I'm making myself clear. Btw, I'm using SAP HANA as a data source, in case that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **Calculated Table**:

```
Table 2 = 
VAR tbl =
    SUMMARIZE(
        'Table', 
        'Table'[NAME], 
        "Count", COUNT('Table'[NAME])
    )
RETURN
    GROUPBY(
        tbl,
        [Count],
        "Distinct Names", COUNTX(CURRENTGROUP(), [Count])
    )
```

It will result in:

[image]

Comment: It would work on an Import model; but I'm not able to create Tables with Direct Query since it's a live connection :(

Comment: You can switch to composite model, but you need to enable the according preview features.